# RouteValueDictionary to HtmlAttributes

Tags: c#, razor, tagbuilder

I know I can add html attributes to my tag by doing something like:

```
var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary { { "data-foo", "bar" } };
var tag = new TagBuilder("div");
tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes );
@tag
```

Output:

```
<div data-foo="bar"></div>
```

I wonder if I can add attributes in a similar way by using markup instead of a tag builder.  Maybe something like:

```
var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary { { "data-foo", "bar" } };
<div @htmlAttributes.ToHtmlAttributes() ></div>
```

Expected output:

```
<div data-foo="bar"></div>
```

Clearly, I wouldn't be able to handle merge conflicts this way.  However, I think it's worth it because the second way is so much more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own extension method:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public static class RouteValueDictionaryExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString ToHtmlAttributes(this RouteValueDictionary dictionary)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\" ", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            }
            return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

which will be used exactly how you've described:

```
@using SomeNamespace    
@{
    var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            {"data-foo", "bar"},
            {"data-bar", "foo"}
        };
}

<div @htmlAttributes.ToHtmlAttributes()> </div>
```

the result is:

```
<div data-foo="bar" data-bar="foo" > </div>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use `TagBuilder`, you can alternatively write another extension which uses it internally:

```
public static IHtmlString Tag(this HtmlHelper helper, 
                              RouteValueDictionary dictionary, 
                              string tagName)
{
    var tag = new TagBuilder(tagName);
    tag.MergeAttributes(dictionary);
    return new HtmlString(tag.ToString());
}
```

and the usage shown below below gives the same output html as previously:

```
@Html.Tag(htmlAttributes, "div")
```

Comment: This seems reasonable.  However, I know `TagBuilder` must do something like this, so I thought that `System.Web` may expose a method that accomplishes this functionality.  Do you know if one exists?

Comment: @steaks: I don't know if such out of the box extension method exists, but `TagBuilder` itself can be used in the way I've shown you in the edited section of my answer.

Comment: I'm going with `ToHtmlAttributes`.  However, I also, like your helper to create a tag.  It's nice improvement to the IMO clunky TagBuilder API.  One improvement I'd suggest is to include an extra parameter `Func<object, HelperResult> innerHtml`.  Use that parameter to set innerHtml `tag.InnerHtml = innerHtml(null).ToHtmlString();`. Also, you can accomplish the same functionality with a using block (which I like better).  Have `Tag` return `IDisposable`.  Then use `tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag)`, `tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag)`, and `System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.Writer` appropriately.